# How to modify color of word cloud generator

Tags: d3.js, svg, word-cloud

I'm creating Word Cloud Generator with using [Jason Davies's Word Cloud Generator](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/#%2F%2Fwww.jasondavies.com%2Fwordcloud%2Fabout%2F), and I want to set the color of text in **SVG** according to weight of text. For example:

```
var tags = [
            { key: 'first', value: 780 },
            { key: 'second', value: 23 }
        ]
```

I want color of key '*first*' to be **more highlight** of key '*second*'

Answer (score 3):

d3's scale() function can be used for generating a color gradient too.

See the example below

```
var tags = [
        { key: 'first', value: 780 },
        { key: 'second', value: 23 }
    ];

var maxValue = d3.max(tags,function(d){ return +d.value});
var minValue = d3.min(tags,function(d){ return +d.value});
var centerValue = (maxValue + minValue)/2;

//color gradient
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([minValue, centerValue, maxValue])
    .range(["red", "white", "green"]);//define your gradient range colors

tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    tag.color = color(+tag.value);
});
```

**Output tags**

```
[{"key":"first","value":780,"color":"#ff0000"},{"key":"second","value":23,"color":"#008000"}]
```

Reference http://synthesis.sbecker.net/articles/2012/07/16/learning-d3-part-6-scales-colors